# Excluding some results from SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a project that is sort of like FB. So I have friends (that are stored in "Requests" by having a request between 2 users with a "Response" of 1. I also have "Circles" that are like friend groups. What I want is a SELECT that returns all friends not in a given circle. I believe the Query is correct up until the "AND NOT" at which point I want to exclude all requests (friends) that have either the sender or reciever (I know it is spelled wrong) of the Response who are already contained in the circle.

```
SELECT us.Username ,
       ur.Username
FROM Requests r 
Join Users    us ON us.UserID = r.Sender 
JOIN Users    ur ON ur.UserID = r.Reciever 
WHERE (    Sender   = ( SELECT UserID
                        FROM Users
                        WHERE Username=?
                      ) 
        OR Reciever = ( SELECT UserID
                        FROM Users
                        WHERE Username = ?
                      )
      ) 
  AND Response=1 
  AND NOT ON ( SELECT un.Username
               FROM CircleMembers c 
               Join Users         un ON un.UserID = c.UserID 
               WHERE CircleID = ( SELECT CircleID
                                  FROM Circles WHERE Name = ?
                                )
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your code sample is incomplete: you're missing (at least) a closing parenthesis.

Comment: I realized that, but that did not help to fix my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query should work:

```
SELECT us.Username, ur.Username 
FROM Requests r 
Join Users us ON us.UserID = r.Sender 
JOIN Users ur ON ur.UserID = r.Reciever
WHERE (us.Username = ? OR ur.Username = ?)
  AND r.Response = 1
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Circles c
    JOIN CircleMembers cm ON c.CircleID = cm.CircleID
    WHERE c.Name = ?
    AND cm.UserID IN (us.UserID, ur.UserID)
  )
```

Comment: I dont really understand you're explanation. My issue is that the request could have either been sent by the current user or received by the current user. In either case I want to display the other person in the request, unless they are already in the circle. Is this not possible?

Comment: Oh, that wasn't clear from your question. In that case you should be using OR, not AND.  Updated.

Comment: I figured that out right as you edited it and got very confused when I went into modify it to be what I was intending. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
AND column_name NOT IN (SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE...)
```